# RailsAdmin has_many direct creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many, rails-admin

I have a simple `has_many` attachments situation:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :images, :class_name => 'ProjectImage', :dependent => :destroy

class ProjectImage < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :image
    belongs_to :project
```

Is it possible (via Rails Admin) to directly add images when creating/editting project?

Now there are two ways (both suck!):

1) Create/Edit a ProjectImage instance and add it to the project (you have to search for it).

2) `Add a new Project image` which creates a modal and is afterwards same as 1)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is: **nested attributes** using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

eg:

```
has_many :images, :class_name => 'ProjectImage', :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :project
accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => true
```